# How to use IO.inspect on a long list without trimming it?

Tags: elixir

When I do:

```
IO.inspect [:right, :top, :left, ...very_long_list]
```

I only get the first items (it's a list of moves to solve a 15-puzzle) like this:

```
[:right, :top, :left, :bot, :bot, :left, :top, :top, :right, :right, :bot,
  :left, :bot, :left, :top, :right, :bot, :right, :top, :top, :left, :bot,
  :left, :top, :right, :right, :bot, :bot, :left, :top, :top, :left, :bot,
  :right, :top, :right, :bot, :left, :left, :top, :right, :bot, :right, :top,
  :left, :left, :bot, ...] # => See the '...'
                                instead, I would like 
                                to get the complete list
```

How can I tell `IO.inspect` to not trim the list? Is there an option or something?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

See [`Inspect.Opts`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Inspect.Opts.html) for a description of the available options:

> - `:limit` - limits the number of items that are printed for tuples,   bitstrings, maps, lists and any other collection of items. It does not
>     apply to strings nor charlists and defaults to 50. If you don't want
>     to limit   the number of items to a particular number, use
>     `:infinity`.

Thus you can pass `limit: :infinity` to print all elements:

```
IO.inspect(list, limit: :infinity)
```

For strings and charlists there is a special option called `:printable_limit`. Both of these options can be combined to ensure that all elements are fully printed.

Comment: Indeed it does, do you know where I can find a list of all the options available ?

Comment: Fire up `iex` and type `h inspect`, it will tell you to look at `h Inspect.Opts` which shows you all options.

Answer (score 35):

For those who wants this for strings which above solution is not for.

Use `printable_limit: integer/:infinity`
https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Inspect.Opts.html