# How to see complete list of `Process.registered()` without truncation?

Tags: elixir

I want to see the complete list of registered local service.

The following codes have been tried already, but list has been trancated, how to solve it?

```
IO.inspect(Process.registered())

Logger.debug("#{inspect Process.registered()}")

Logger.debug(Process.registered())
```

Trancation result are as follows:

```
[:code_server, :dtls_listener_sup, Hex.Supervisor,
 :tls_server_session_ticket_sup, :ssl_connection_sup, :kernel_safe_sup,
 :ssl_upgrade_server_session_cache_sup, :elixir_code_server, :httpc_handler_sup,
 :tls_client_ticket_store, Mix.TasksServer, :disk_log_sup,
 :logger_std_h_ssl_handler, :erl_prim_loader, :logger_proxy,
 :dtls_server_session_cache_sup, IEx.Supervisor, :application_controller,
 :httpc_sup, Mix.ProjectStack, :ssl_sup, :inet_db, :ssl_listen_tracker_sup,
 :kernel_refc, Logger, :dtls_sup, :rex, :logger_handler_watcher, :httpd_sup,
 :standard_error_sup, :ssl_manager, IEx.Pry, :erts_code_purger, :httpc_manager,
 :user_drv, :tls_connection_sup, :erl_signal_server, :user, Hex.Registry.Server,
 IEx.Config, :kernel_sup, :elixir_sup, :hex_fetcher, :tls_server_sup,
 :ssl_admin_sup, Hex.Netrc.Cache, :ssl_server_session_cache_sup,
 Logger.Supervisor, Mix.Supervisor, :disk_log_server, ...]
```

Process.registered()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [limit](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Inspect.Opts.html) option for `IO.inspect`. Run `IO.inspect(Process.registered, limit: :infinity)` and you will see a full list.

Answer (score 2):

For iex, you can [configure](https://hexdocs.pm/iex/IEx.html#configure/1-inspect) it to not trim the output:

```elixir
IEx.configure(inspect: [limit: :infinity])
```

You can also put this in [`.iex.exs`](https://hexdocs.pm/iex/IEx.html#module-the-iex-exs-file) if you want to preserve this setting across sessions.

This means you can just call `Process.registered()` in iex without using `IO.inspect` and will see the full result.

For `IO.inspect`, this question is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29566248/how-to-use-io-inspect-on-a-long-list-without-trimming-it).