# Elixir list is ending in periods

Tags: list, elixir, elixir-iex

I am trying to return a list in Elixir that has a length of 52 but the list always ends up being returned with the last two elements being turned to periods.

I tested it in the iex in command prompt using:

`list = [10,11,12,13,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`

The returned value was `[10, 11, 12, 13, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, ...]`

Comment: could be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/29566391/3507061

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behavior in IEx is to truncate long lists or maps. I believe the limit is 50 items.

You can either explicitly call inspect or IO.inspect, e.g. `IO.inspect(foo, limit: :infinity)` as your second parameter, or you can temporarily globally set the default to something more practical, say, 200 or 500, by changing the configuration of IEx.

```
IEx.configure(inspect: [limit: :infinity])
```

Replace `:infinity` with a specific number if you might have an extremely long list over a terminal.